# Does Graph API support custom header to be used as search filter?

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail, custom-headers

As we all know EWS provide support for MessageClass can be used while searching emails having particular MessageClass value.

Does Graph API also support similar functionality for searching emails from user mailbox?

Comment: I don't have the subject on EWS but may be you can use [Query Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Extended property, we can use Message Class to filter emails from mailbox store.
Following link is very useful for them, who are planning to migrate EWS based application to Graph based.

https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2020/03/migrating-your-mailbox-searches-in-ews.html

Answer (score 0):

Using **$search** on message collections, you can search messages based on a value in specific message properties.
The results of the search are sorted by the date and time that the message was sent. A $search request returns up to 250 results.

Sample Request - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="pizza"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search=%22pizza%22) (GET)

Please refer to [search parameter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) to understand better.

Also, in addition to that, you can leverage **Microsoft Search API** to search Outlook messages.

Refer to Example 1 in documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages) for the same.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I went through the links you suggested, unfortunately I could not find any available documentation regarding support of "customer header" as search filter in Graph API.

Comment: How about using  Extensions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview)  for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

ItemClass isn't a first class property in the graph so if you want to use it in a Filter you need to use the singleValueExtendedProperties defination of the MAPI messageclass property and filter on that eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'String 0x001a' and ep/value eq 'IPM.Note')
```

One pain point with the Graph is that it only lets you access particular MessageClass's and SubClass of those via the Messages endpoint.